# Shortened dictionary PYTHON

Tags: python

I´m looking to make a dictionary which sets every letter in the alphabet to its numeric value for example a:1 like this.

```
alphabet = dict([ (chr(97+i), i+1) for i in range(0, 26) ])
```

However once it gets to z I need it the alphabet to loop once more but the value must continue from 26 for example z:26, a:27, b:28 and so on. How will I do this without writing the dictionary out manually?

Comment: You cannot have an entry for 'a': 1 and 'a': 27 at the same time, that would make alphabet['a'] ambiguous. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: A dictionary can't have duplicate keys, so `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, ... 'z': 26, 'a': 27, 'b': 28, ...}` is impossible. Or do you want `{1: 'a', 2: 'b', ... 27: 'a', 28: 'b'}`? That would be fine.

Comment: Please explain your goal, there may be a shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually want to do this, you just think you do! Dictionaries can't have duplicate keys, which makes this actually impossible.

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, ..., 'a':27}  # doesn't work the way you think it does!
>>> d
{'a': 27}  # where'd the a->1 mapping go!
```

What you should do instead is write a function that does the lookup, and use the modulo operator `%` to "wrap" the range.

```
def char_lookup(ord_):
    """Maps 1->a, 2->b, etc. Handles 27->a, 28->b, ..."""
    OFFSET = 97
    return chr((ord_-1) % 26 + OFFSET)
```

Then instead of doing `d[27]` and getting `'a'`, do `char_lookup(27)`.

As Lattyware points out in the comments, it's possible you're trying to get a range of values given the character, instead of a character given a range of values. In which case you could do something like:

```
import string
d = {ch:[i, i+26] for i,ch in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, start=1)}
```

`d` then looks like:

```
{'a': [1, 27], 'b': [2, 28], ...}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this does the opposite mapping to the one shown in the question. It may be this works for the asker, but it's an important difference.

Comment: @Lattyware Irrelevant since the mapping shown in the question is impossible. This seems to accomplish the only reasonable lookup that OP could want.

Comment: Impossible? You can have maps to lists of values. You have made a (reasonable) assumption about what the asker wants, but it is not the only possible answer, and it may be completely useless depending on the use case. You should state clearly when you make such assumptions.

Comment: @Lattyware The mapping shown in the question is `{'a': 1, ..., 'a': 27}` which is of course nonsense. `{'a': [1, 27]}` is obviously possible, but suffers the same problem of "not matching the question" as my proposed answer.

Comment: My point is not that your answer is not a good one, or that another is better, merely that due to the nature of the question (that it asks for something impossible) there are multiple potential answers, and you should make it clear where yours differs from what was asked for.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, as no one has given an answer preserving the key-value roles, I give an example that does.

It is impossible to have multiple values for the same key, however, you can have an iterable of values as the value, which can be used to emulate multiple values per key:

```
>>> alphabet = {chr(i + 97): itertools.count(i + 1, 26) for i in range(0, 26)}
>>> a = alphabet["a"]
>>> next(a)
1
>>> next(a)
27
```

Here I am using a dictionary comprehension, as it's a little nicer to read - if you are using a very old version of Python, you may instead need to use:

```
dict((chr(i + 97), itertools.count(i + 1, 26)) for i in range(0, 26))
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary can't have duplicate keys that point to different values, so `d = {'a': 1, 'a': 27}` won't work.  You can however reverse that so that the keys are your numbers instead... something like this would work:

```
import string

d = {}

for i, l in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase):
    d[i+1] = l
    d[i+27] = l
```

Result:

```
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e', 6: 'f', 7: 'g', 8: 'h', 9: 'i', 10: 'j', 11: 'k', 12: 'l', 13: 'm', 14: 'n', 15: 'o', 16: 'p', 17: 'q', 18: 'r', 19: 's', 20: 't', 21: 'u', 22: 'v', 23: 'w', 24: 'x', 25: 'y', 26: 'z', 27: 'a', 28: 'b', 29: 'c', 30: 'd', 31: 'e', 32: 'f', 33: 'g', 34: 'h', 35: 'i', 36: 'j', 37: 'k', 38: 'l', 39: 'm', 40: 'n', 41: 'o', 42: 'p', 43: 'q', 44: 'r', 45: 's', 46: 't', 47: 'u', 48: 'v', 49: 'w', 50: 'x', 51: 'y', 52: 'z'}
```

Comment: This is the reverse of the dictionary the original poster wants.

Comment: @Lattyware As stated before, a dictionary can't have duplicate keys, so this is the next best option.

Comment: It is? That largely depends on the use case. It should at least be mentioned in your answer that this is an alternative, and explain the difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that 'cycles', ie starts again from a after you pass 26 (or 25, if you start from 0), then what you need is not a dictionary but a function (because as pointed in the comments, python dictionaries can't have duplicate keys). So try something like:

```
def alphabet(i):
    i = i%26
    return chr(97+i)
```

You can test this with this simple loop:

```
for i in range(200):
    print(alphabet(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an other way to achieve what you need:

```
a = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
b = list(range(1,53))
c = [x for x in a*2]
d = dict(zip(b,c))
```

The output for `d`

```
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e', 6: 'f', 7: 'g', 8: 'h', 9: 'i', 10: 'j', 11: 'k', 12: 'l', 13: 'm', 14: 'n', 15: 'o', 16: 'p', 17: 'q', 18: 'r', 19: 's', 20: 't', 21: 'u', 22: 'v', 23: 'w', 24: 'x', 25: 'y', 26: 'z', 27: 'a', 28: 'b', 29: 'c', 30: 'd', 31: 'e', 32: 'f', 33: 'g', 34: 'h', 35: 'i', 36: 'j', 37: 'k', 38: 'l', 39: 'm', 40: 'n', 41: 'o', 42: 'p', 43: 'q', 44: 'r', 45: 's', 46: 't', 47: 'u', 48: 'v', 49: 'w', 50: 'x', 51: 'y', 52: 'z'}
```